# Visual studio function list windows not contain all functions

Tags: c, visual-studio

Now visual studio function list windows not contain all functions, but instead contains macros that are used within it code.

Here an example:

[image]
For instance macros DebugTrace is defined as follow:

```
 #define DebugTrace(Level, Data)                      \
    if ((Level) <= filterData.DebugLevel) {          \
        DbgPrint Data;                               \
            }
```

I am using VS 2013 update 3. Looks like VS bug. What is the reason and how can I force it to show list of functions correctly?

Comment: Is it possible to replace these with templated functions?

Comment: Not always.. sometimes macros are better. Especially in C where there isn't templated functions.

Comment: Have you tried closing VS, then deleting the `<SolutionName>.sdf` file and reopening the solution? This will cause VS to recreate its code browsing database (can take a while), which might get rid of the incorrect entries. Also it doesn't seem to happen for me, do you have a minimal example to reproduce this?

Comment: @user2802841 deleting the <SolutionName>.sdf - not helps... I know that this happens for my c driver solutions in all modules

Comment: remember that macros are text replacement specifiers, not function names.  The example (to me) is not showing a problem.  Please clarify just what the problem is.